# Visual studio desginer view is zoomed, how can i get the actual size?

Tags: forms, visual-studio, size, zooming, designer

[Image Problem: form designer bigger then actual size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZUIc.png)

Maybe this is a stupid question but I havn't found any solution. So my designer view is zoomed(like 150% bigger) than the actual size, I want my desginer view to be normal. There is no problems with the form properties or something else. You will see what I mean on the image.

Anyone who knows how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: i think this answers your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119740/zooming-in-the-visual-studio-form-designer

Comment: I had read that and I have tried it with an other monitor but it was not changed. Also yesterday was my designer view normal, it was suddenly changed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case something strange was with DPI setting in my Windows 10 system.

Solution was `change DPI setting` (Change the size of text,...) in `Display settings`, logout / login into system and change DPI setting back. After next login designer zoom was recovered.