# Visual Studio (2022) and display scaling with winforms

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, screen-resolution

Since I have to work in a winforms project again, I do have problems with the VS designer now. I have a Thinkpad P1 with FullHD (16" WUXGA = 1920 x 1200) and a 125 % scaling because the 100 % scaling is too small for my old eyes on the laptop screen. The scaling now leeds to unpredictable VS (winforms) designer views, usually I cannot trust what I see. So, no WYSIWYG at all. ;) Does it help to buy a laptop with higher resolution (WQXGA = 2560 x 1600) or does that just worsen the problem? After so many years, I start to like the WPF designer! :)

Comment: You issue is probably related to DpiAwareness (a WPF app is already DpiAware). You need a recent version of .NET (4.7.2+ for .NET FX). If you're targeting .NET, better target .NET 7+ and, in any case, select the `PerMonitorV2` DpiAware mode (the default in .NET, unfortunately, is `SystemAware`) -- Add the .NET version you're planning to target (if you can choose, then pick .NET 7)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737619/how-to-turn-off-different-dpi-scaling-in-winform/77753975#77753975 may be of help

Answer (score -1):

For what you said, setting a scaling factor of 125% has an effect on the Winforms designer, mainly because [Windows Forms Designer does not scale, WPF does this because it is vector-based, but WinForms is pixel-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119740/zooming-in-the-visual-studio-form-designer).

For this issue, usually [click the "Restart Visual Studio with 100% scaling" option or set the Visual Studio software to ignore Windows' DPI display scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2022).

But this again seems to bypass the problem you mentioned in your post: "100% zoom is too small for old eyes on a laptop screen", so use a high resolution laptop or use a high resolution The external display is a very good solution

Comment: You mean a laptop with a larger screen to run in 100 % scaling, right?

Comment: @IngoB Yes, that's what it means